# How can I change PDF output font from within the YAML header when using Pandoc on Markdown?

Tags: fonts, pandoc

Is there a (built-in) way to set a different font (or fonts) to use in the Pandoc YAML header? Ideally, I would do something like this in the YAML header of my Markdown file:

```
---
font: MySansSerifFontName  
...
```

I'm using TexLive on Linux (Ubuntu), with `pandoc`, of course.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
---
fontfamily: arev
---
```

From Pandoc's [README](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/README.html#templates):

> **fontfamily**: font package to use for LaTeX documents (with pdflatex): TeXLive has `bookman` (Bookman), `utopia` or `fourier` (Utopia), `fouriernc` (New Century Schoolbook), `times` or `txfonts` (Times), `mathpazo` or `pxfonts` or `mathpple` (Palatino), `libertine` (Linux Libertine), `arev` (Arev Sans), and the default `lmodern`, among others.

Answer (score 8):

When you use **xelatex** or **lualatex** to render the PDF you must use:

```
---
mainfont: Arial
---
```

Official documentation: [Variables for LaTeX](http://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#variables-for-latex)